# How to skip a cookbook according to node json file

Tags: httpd, chef

I have a cookbook like this.

```
if node['httpd'] == "nginx"

  package "nginx" do
    action :install
  end

  # a lot more stuff

end
```

But I don't want to embrace all setting in a `if` statement.
Is there way to write like this in chef?

```
next if node['httpd'] != "nginx"

package "nginx" do
  action :install
end

# a lot more stuff
```

If `node['httpd']` is not `"nginx"`, I want to go to next cookbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `return` to skip evaluation of the rest of a recipe, e.g.:

```
return if node['httpd'] != 'nginx'

# ...
```